# Gnosis Safe CLI Gas Allowance Function

Tags: gnosis-safe

I am trying to send an erc-20 token from an Optimism Safe to another wallet using CLI. I am trying to modify the gas allowance in the "send erc-20" function like this:

send_erc20 0x7F5c764cBc14f9669B88837ca1490cCa17c31607 0x1dE****ab4Bc 1 --gas 600000 --gasPrice 20

But I get the "unrecognized argument error":

: error: unrecognized arguments: --gas 600000 --gasPrice 20

What am I doing wrong? How can I modify the gas allowance to send the token to another wallet? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The error message seems quite clear. Have you tried dropping the gas options?

Comment: Yeah and when I try to drop the gas options it say gas amount exceeds allowance. I'm not sure how I can add gass options correctly.

Comment: then it means you don't have enough funds to pay the gas

Comment: Thank you for that. Can you also help me with why this command doesn't work:

 send_erc20 0x7F5c764cBc14f9669B88837ca1490cCa17c31607 0x1dE----ab4Bc 1

It actually sends the transaction but the amount of USDC (in this case 1) isn't transferred to the address mentioned. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's not enough info to debug, it would be helpful to see the transaction. One potential reason is that you're passing the value without token decimals (USDC has 6 decimals, so 1 USDC would be 1 (amount) * 10^6 (decimal amount) = 1000000)

Comment: It looks like in your original command, the order of addresses is wrong, first should be the recipient address, then the token address and then the amount, according to the docs here: https://github.com/5afe/safe-cli

Comment: so it would be `send_erc20 <recipient> <token_address> 350933508`

Comment: It worked! I had tried the correct command before but the problem was with the number. I never considered the decimals. Thank you so much for the help. I really appreciate it.